# Google Protocol Buffer Repeated Field Memory Leak

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I'm running Deleaker and getting this:

```
ntdll.dll!RtlCreateActivationContext + 2769 bytes 000000007719fac0
TestParserLibrary.exe!_heap_alloc_base Line 58 + 0x5d bytes 000000013fb91b6d
TestParserLibrary.exe!_heap_alloc_dbg_impl Line 431 + 0x27b bytes 000000013fb6b2eb
TestParserLibrary.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg_impl Line 239 + 0x39 bytes 000000013fb6b8c9
TestParserLibrary.exe!_nh_malloc_dbg Line 302 + 0x49 bytes 000000013fb6b859
TestParserLibrary.exe!malloc Line 56 + 0x2a bytes 000000013fb8312a
TestParserLibrary.exe!operator new Line 59 + 0x13 bytes 000000013fb61ec3
TestParserLibrary.exe!google::protobuf::internal::InitializeDefaultRepeatedFields Line 1630 + 0x2e bytes 000000013faf252e
TestParserLibrary.exe!google::protobuf::internal::StaticDefaultRepeatedFieldsInitializer::StaticDefaultRepeatedFieldsInitializer Line 1624 + 0x23 bytes 000000013faf7993
TestParserLibrary.exe!google::protobuf::internal::`dynamic initializer for 'static_repeated_fields_initializer'' Line 1626 + 0x21 bytes 000000013f8f78b1
TestParserLibrary.exe!_initterm Line 955 + 0x2c bytes 000000013fb8431c
TestParserLibrary.exe!_cinit Line 321 + 0x74 bytes 000000013fb83f34
TestParserLibrary.exe!__tmainCRTStartup Line 237 + 0xb1 bytes 000000013fb6eb81
TestParserLibrary.exe!wmainCRTStartup Line 165 + 0xe bytes 000000013fb6ecfe
kernel32.dll!GetFileSizeEx + 51 bytes 00000000770459cd
ntdll.dll!memcpy + 38401 bytes 000000007717b981
```

This seems to be a problem with the Repeated Field in the Protocol Buffer message. I know it is probably triggered by some of my code, but I have no idea what the cause is.

Has anybody come across it before?

Comment: What version of protobuf do you use?

Comment: Just found similar report: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=503696